# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I open XAMPP and click start MySQL button and it gives me an error. I had started it just before, but now it isn't working.

```
19:53:07  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
19:53:07  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
19:53:07  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
19:53:07  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
19:53:07  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
19:53:07  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
19:53:07  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
19:53:07  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Here is the contents of the error log:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 519973; transaction id 604
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

The most important error message is here:

```
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 519973; transaction id 604
2019-09-05 19:53:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
```

I watched tutorials on yt but it isnt work.....